# Partial Array filter

Tags: javascript, lodash

i got the following array of objects

```
[
        {
                "name": "Jack Daniel",
                "job": "Software Developer",
                "age" : "40M"
        },
        {
                "name": "Sofia Daniel",
                "job": "Web Developer",
                "age" : "35F"
        },
        {
                "name": "John Smith",
                "job": "Marketing",
                "age" : "32M"
        },
        {
                "name": "Clara Johnson",
                "job": "Designer",
                "age" : "35F"
        }
]
```

now using lodash i can filter for age or any property i like but how can i achieve the following.

1. Search for 35 and get a list of all objects with age 35F
2. Search for Daniel and get all objects whose name has Daniel?

I got a feeling it is very simple.

Comment: Please search before posting, this question has been asked repeatedly before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+filter+array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter()` with `indexOf()` in pure javascript.

```js
var data = [{"name":"Jack Daniel","job":"Software Developer","age":"40M"},{"name":"Sofia Daniel","job":"Web Developer","age":"35F"},{"name":"John Smith","job":"Marketing","age":"32M"},{"name":"Clara Johnson","job":"Designer","age":"35F"}]

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return e.age.indexOf(35) != -1 && e.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('daniel') != -1;
})

console.log(result);
```